# URLbar still selected after loading page on Safari on Catalina

Tags: keyboard, safari, catalina

I am using `Safari` with `Vimari` on my macOS `Catalina`. Problem is whenever I am navigating to some url by pressing designated key(provided by Vimari) after pressing `F`, the URL bar still stays focused rather than loaded page. Every time I am loading a URL in the browser I have to press tab or click on webpage to select it and then start scrolling using `J/K`. If I don't select the webpage, keypresses goes to URL bar rather than currently loaded page.

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Would seem like you should be reporting this at https://github.com/televator-apps/vimari